# Why does "char *ptr={'R','E','D','\0'};" gives too many warnings while "char *ptr="RED";" works fine?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, array-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char *ptr={'R','E','D','\0'};
   //char *ptr="RED";
}
```

It shows the following list of warnings:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast|
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer|
warning: (near initialization for 'ptr')|
```

But if works fine if I comment out the first statement and activate the second statement (which is commented out in my code).

Why is it so?Why isn't a pointer to the same array not assigned to `ptr` in the first case,just as it is in the second case?What is the rigorous technical reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 6.7.9 (11) [of the N1570 draft, identical in 6.7.8 (11) of C99], it is specified that

> **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.** The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

By providing more than a single expression in

```
char *ptr={'R','E','D','\0'};
```

you're violating a "shall" requirement and invoke undefined behaviour (4 (2)):

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

That out of the way, this particular kind of undefined behaviour usually mainfests as the compiler ignoring all but the first expression - except for the generation of the

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer|
```

and treats the code as if it was

```
char *ptr = {'R'};
```

then, which unsurprisingly leads to the

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast|
```

since `'R'` is an integer and not a pointer.

On the other hand,

```
char *ptr = "RED";
```

is perfectly fine because the array<sup>(1)</sup> `"RED"` is converted to a pointer to its initial element in the initialisation, like it would be for assignment.

<sup>(1)</sup> String literals are arrays, not pointers, as told in section 6.4.5 (6):

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. **The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.** For character string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence. For UTF−8 string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the characters of the multibyte character sequence, as encoded in UTF−8.

(wide string literals are arrays of type `wchar_t[N]`, `char16_t[N]` or `char32_t[N]`, depending on whether they are prefixed with `L`, `u` or `U`.)

Comment: But **H2CO3** says the string literal `"RED"` is of type `char[4]`, not `char*`,but **paxdiablo** says it is of type `char*`.Who is right?

Comment: If I am right, your answer says in its last line that the string literal is indeed of type `char[4]` but it is converted to pointer `char*` before assignment to `ptr`.Right?

Comment: Yes, the type of `"RED"` is `char[4]`, as H2CO3 said, and that array undergoes array-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: Jesus Christ!!What made **paxdiablo** delete his answer Mr.Fischer?

Comment: I am glad I posted this seemingly trivial question instead of shrugging it off.I learnt so much new stuff due to it.